In what use cases can Orkes Conductor be used for microservices orchestration?
How is Orkes Conductor used in real world microservices based applications? Can it be used to coordinate the interactions between services as in business process management or in saga coordination?
I have tried using Orkes conductor for implementing Sagas in microservices and I am looking for other real world use cases in which Conductor is used.

Here is one example of using orkes for an audio encoding and delievery pipeline, you can think of each bullet point as a task (micro service worker). The tasks make up a workflow.

Analyze an audio file for metadata
Convert audio into various different audio encodings (mp3, mp4, hls)
Upload audio encodings to a CDN
Perform HTTP posts to publish CDN locations to APIs
Notify people via email or slack

This could easily be done all as a large service but by breaking up the components into micro services they can be used by other workflows for other use cases without writing/changing large amounts of code.
